# Working with Google Cloud Print

Tags: google-cloud-print

I have begun digging around in the Google Cloud Print project in hopes of creating a custom application for my network.  I have a Windows Print Server running with a printer queue I wish to submit jobs to.  Setup the Google Cloud Print with the Crome browser and I was able to submit and print jobs just fine.  However, my end goal is a little more complicated.

I need to customize the access control from the server-side client endpoint once the job reaches my network.  Meaning, once the job is submitted, I need to be able to check the username of the owner of the job and process accordingly.  From the looks of it, the /fetch interface does not store the original owner of the job, just the end owner of the queue it ends up on.  Meaning, User A has the Google Cloud Printer linked to their account and has shared it with User B.  User B submits a job to the shared queue.  When I run /fetch on the shared printerID the user is User A.

Has anyone else dabbled with this?

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with App Engine? Or programming, for that matter?

Comment: Umm, not sure I understand what you mean.  This is in reference to the Google Cloud Print API at https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/pythonCode.  Pretty sure that is in reference to the App Engine and programming, python programing to be specific.

Comment: Cloud print is an API that you can access from any webapp. Are you writing an app on App Engine to use this? If so, is it relevant to your question that you're doing that? You don't mention anything in your question that would make it App Engine specific.

Comment: @jomilie how to take print? i did sign in to Google Cloud printer with my account.., but printer is not showing in the list.. did i miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `ownerId` of the job.

The /fetch call does in fact return a `user` field containing the owner of the printer (User A), but the specific job(s) returned contains an `ownerId` field with a value of the user that submitted the print job (User B).

Hope that helps.

Following is a partial response from a /fetch call, including ownerId of the job. Keep in mind that this could be one of many jobs that are returned in the `jobs` array:

```
...
updateTime: "1403628993840",
status: "QUEUED",
ownerId: "rpreeves@gmail.com",
rasterUrl: "https://www.google.com/cloudprint/download?id=5ca7b1e4-c533-c42b-7d2b-efb862c4215a&forcepwg=1",
ticketUrl: "https://www.google.com/cloudprint/ticket?format=ppd&output=json&jobid=5ca7b1e4-c633-c42b-782b-efb862c4215a",
printerid: "f33c6ff8-fc25-7075-249b-ab65c3e2354e",
...
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't show that; it only mentions ownerId in the /list call.  

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/proxyinterfaces#fetch  

Do you have an example /fetch response which you could post to demonstrate that it has ownerId (obviously redacting any info that's sensitive)?  

If you're right, that's probably the mechanism that FedEx uses to support this "follow me" printing service:  
http://www.fedex.com/us/office/cloud-printing.html

Comment: Just added an example. Yes, I believe FedEx relies on the job ownerId to send notifications and the "retrieval" code.